# Google Script converts numbers differently than javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to convert a string to an int. When the string is a number with a leading zero, it seems Google Script gets into trouble. Converting "07" to 7 works fine, converting "08" ends in a NaN.

```
function test_parse_int() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // parses to 7
  ss.toast( parseInt("07") );
  // parses to NaN ?!?
  ss.toast( parseInt("08") );
}
```

I tested that against JavaScript and there it works fine.

```
<script>
// parses to 7
document.writeln(parseInt("07"));
// parses to 8
document.writeln(parseInt("08"));
</script>
```

This behaviour doesn't make any sense to me, is this a bug? Am i missing something?

Comment: The keyword is "octal", use the radix argument to [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) correctly.

Comment: "Many implementations have not adopted this behavior as of 2013, and because older browsers must be supported, always specify a radix"

Alright, i see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt [Credits to @teemu comment]

> If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal) or 10
>   (decimal).  Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent.
>   ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers
>   support this yet.  For this reason always specify a radix when using
>   parseInt.

So explicityly mention the `radix`

Something like this :

```
function test_parse_int() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // parses to 7
  ss.toast( parseInt("07", 10) );
  // parses to NaN ?!?
  ss.toast( parseInt("08", 10) );
}
```